# Android Java save video from url to gallery API 19-30

Tags: java, android, video, download, save

I am trying to save a video from a url to the gallery for ages now. I have found multiple solutions (including the one I will append) but none of them worked for the api levels my app covers (19-30) and not on all devices.
I have saved my videos in a cloud storage (e.g. firebase) and got the url. I only want to save it at the TOP of the gallery so it can be found immediately.

Is there a definite approach which works on all devices and api levels? I am really struggling.

```
                    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(post.vUrl);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Flax."+post.date);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
                request.setMimeType("video/mp4");
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

This code will NOT save it to gallery and some devices are not able to even open the file at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it does not save to the gallery (whatever that would be) then where does it save to instead?

Comment: And how does a device try to open such a file? And what is the TOP of a gallery?

Comment: `"Flax."+post.date` We have no idea what such a file name would look like.

Comment: `am trying to save a video from a url to the gallery for ages now.` I think you asked the DownloadManager to do that for you.

Comment: "I only want to save it at the TOP of the gallery so it can be found immediately" -- a gallery is a type of app. It is not a place. How a gallery app behaves is up to the developers of the gallery app, not you. "Android Java save video from url to gallery API 19-30" -- [this example](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos) demonstrates downloading videos from a URL to the device. It is written in Kotlin, though.

Comment: I need it to be in Java as I do not use kotlin at all and never used it before